# React-native componentWillMount not calling

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new in react-native I have two screens in my stack. Login and Home.

I want to go back to login from a button on home.

I am writing this code

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('loginScreen')
```

but in login screen **componentWillMount** method is not calling. I want to reset my form when user come on login screen from home.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go back from login from home , you should use `this.props.navigation.goBack()` if the screen is immidiately before `home`.

Secondly, you should not use `componentWillMount` since it is deprecated and will be removed from **React 17** onwards. Instead use `componentDidMount`

Since the component is already mounted therefore it won't call the react lifecycle events `componentDidMount` again. Therefore you should use the `react-navigation` [listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) `didFocus` event.

> **didFocus**: the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

```
componentDidMount () {
    this._onFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', (payload) => {
      // Perform the reset action here
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked but one more issue, props are not setting from home to login
Login screen:-

componentDidMount () {
    this._onFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', (payload) => {
      // Perform the reset action here
      if (this.props.isFromLogedOut == '1') {
      this.setState({
        email: 'aaa',
        password: '',
        enableDoneButton: false
      })
    }
    });
}


Home screen:-

this.props.navigation.navigate('loginStack', { isFromLogedOut: '1' })

Comment: Inside the `payload` you can get the [following](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#state-the-screen-s-current-state-route) details including the `lastState` from where you can check `lastScreen` and its params

Answer (score 2):

The `this.props.navigation.navigate('loginScreen')` don't work because you are now in `loginScreen`.

If you want to restart page this code isn't good. because **have a loop!**

correct code:

**just when `navigate` to `loginScreen` from `home` use:**

```
this.props.navigation.push('loginScreen')
```

**NOT IN "componentWillMount"**

Comment: I am on home screen and want to go back to login, and using the same code you suggested

Comment: Actually this is not a bad answer, just not well formatted. What @morteza is saying is that navigation.navigate() gets you to a previous screen if the screen is already visited or pushes a new one if the screen is not visited before. If you want the componentWillMount of your login screen to be called, then using navigation.push() should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Home and Login Screens are both under the same StackNavigator, when you go from Home back to Login the state stays the same as the component doesn't unmount. The recommended way to solve this is using the SwitchNavigator of react-navigation. Read this very helpful part of the documentation below

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

> You may not be familiar with SwitchNavigator yet. The purpose of
>   SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default,
>   it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default
>   state when you switch away.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution is with `this.props.navigation.push('Login')`, I tried with `SwitchNavigator` but it doesn't provide `navigationOptions` for header.